# Process Hogging CPU/Lag after Power Removed

Tags: 20.04, power-management

I only have this problem occasionally when I remove my laptop from power. Suddenly something starts hogging 100% of one core and there is a noticable lag on pretty much any interaction (mouse movement, typing). When I reboot (off OR on power) it goes back to normal.

In ksysguard, usually there's a process listed as "Web" doing the hogging. When I kill it, it kills all my firefox instances, but then an Xorg process sometimes starts doing it.

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 on a HP Pavillion with an Intel i7 and an NVidia graphics card. I have completely reinstalled my OS, doing a clean install from 19 -> 20.04 and the problem persists.

Comment: If it's only happening on battery, I wonder if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117059/1222991) for a similar problem would work for you 

Comment: *"Intel i7 and an NVidia graphics card"* - Gaming laptop?  Most of them are designed to perform worse when they are running off battery. You need to be connected to AC if you want better performance

Comment: What is the CPU frequency when this happens? What is your normal maximum CPU frequency?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @matigo that link looks promising. I also have problems with my laptop going to sleep (sometimes it doesn't turn back on), it seems like that might be related. I'll try to check the CPU frequency next time this happens